# Alert on GridView edit based on permissions

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with an edit option to be able to edit the gridview row. There are also different user permissions available in my web application like Admin, SuperUser, User. If the user is not an `Admin` and he tries to edit a row I need to give an alert like shown below. But the js I used below will give alert for all users since there are no validations set.

**MY TRY SO FAR**

**GridView:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" OnClientClick="myFunction()" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.gif" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function myFunction() {
        var edit;
        if (confirm("For ADMIN only. Do not edit/delete the row. Still want to continue?") == true) {
        }
        else {
            window.location.reload();
        }
        document.getElementById("btnEdit").innerHTML = edit;
    }
```

**Capturing current logged in user:**

Also I have captured the current logged in user in the same page by using the below code. Current logged in user information is saved in a label.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkUser();
}

public void checkUser()
{
    string currentUser = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
    string[] words = currentUser.Split('\\');
    currentUser = words[1];
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;
        string strQuery = "select UserId from Permissions where UserId='" +  currentUser + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
    }
    lblUser.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();
}
```

In `Permissions` table I have a column called Roles and I need to check if the user is not an Admin and need to give an alert. Really appreciate any suggestions or help on this.

Comment: Why bug the user with an alert? That just seems like a frustrated user. Instead, why not hide the edit button for people that don't have access?

Comment: @mason -No they can edit the row, but still I need to show the alert.

Comment: In that case, why use an alert, which disrupts workflow? A notification that informs the user without getting in there way is probably preferable, such as [noty](http://ned.im/noty/).

Comment: @mason - I'm unable to access the link.

Comment: It's just a link to a notification library I like. There are some others out there such as [Notify.js](http://notifyjs.com/) and [alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/),

Answer (score 0):

try this way

Script as

```
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() {
          var edit = confirm("For ADMIN only. Do not edit/delete the row. Still want to continue?");
          if (edit) {
              return true;
          }
          else {
              return false;
          }
       } 
      </script>
```

And Funcation call as OnClientClick="return myFunction();"

Comment: But where in the script am I checking for user roles like if not an admin do this function. I need to give this alert for users who are not admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    Button btnEdit = e.Row.FindControl("btnEdit") as Button;
    if(lblUser.Text !="Admin")
      btnEdit.OnClientClick = "alert('Not allowed');return false;";
  }
}
```

And if you want to use your function you can make change as below:

```
 btnEdit.OnClientClick = "return myFunction()";
```

Comment: I get this error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on this line `btnEdit.OnClientClick = "alert('Not allowed');return false;"; `

Comment: Here e.Row.FindControl("btnEdit") I have searched for button control based on its ID, if you are using for command field than you need to do changes.

Comment: Vicky can you plz paste code which exactly you used and getting error.?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it server side? When you get into the Edit function, check the permissions. That way a 'smart' user can't still edit because he circumvents your client side check.

Comment: I tried `gmd` answer and I get an error I mentioned in this post.

Comment: That's because he's not calling an actual serverside function. What i mean is to make the button click return to the server, and handle the click there

Comment: <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" OnClick="GridRowBtnEditClick" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.gif" />
</ItemTemplate> Then create the GridRowBtnEditClick method, and in there use the CheckUser